# How to host iPhone build files (.ipa files) for enterprise edition

Tags: iphone

What are the possible ways to host iPhone build files (.ipa files) for enterprise edition, so that members of a particular organization can download that file?

Answer (score 0):

Use AdHoc.

> With Ad Hoc distribution you can share your application with up to 100
>   other iPad, iPhone, or iPod touch users. Through email or by posting
>   it to a website or server, users can download and install your app.